# Unexpected behavior of FormattableString.ToString(IFormatProvider)

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm testing string formatting of numbers with different culture settings, using string interpolation (with $"...")

```
        [Fact]
        public void FormattingTest()
        {
            double value = 2012.1234;
            CultureInfo c1 = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-CH");
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            // Works fine - the string is formatted according to the explicitly specified culture
            FormattableString f = $"{value:N2}";
            Assert.Equal("2'012.12", f.ToString(c1));

            // This test fails.
            string f2 = $"{value:N2}".ToString(c1);
            Assert.Equal("2'012.12", f2); // Actual value is formatted according to CurrentCulture.
        }
```

Does somebody know why the second test fails? It looks like the compiler translates this to

```
string f2 = $"{value:N2}"; // Evaluate the interpolation using the current culture.
f2 = f2.ToString(c1); // Does nothing, since f2 has no format specifiers any more
```

This is apparently not what's intended.

Comment: Interpolated strings are only _immediately_ convertible to `FormattableString` or `IFormattable`. Because you're not assigning the interpolated string directly to a `FormattableString` in the second test, it gets typed as `string` and is interpolated using the default culture.

Comment: @JeffE: That's quite unusual behavior. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#interpolated-strings "An _interpolated_string_expression_ is classified as a value. If it is immediately converted to `System.IFormattable` or `System.FormattableString` with an implicit interpolated string conversion (Implicit interpolated string conversions), the interpolated string expression has that type. Otherwise, it has the type `string`."

Comment: @JeffE: Thanks for the link. I still think this concept doesn't match up with how types are generally derived in C#. It is as if the expression `2.ToString()` was of type `int`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your example. The type of `$"{value:N2}"` needs to be resolved before `.ToString(c1)` has any meaning. The rules resolve it to `string`, therefore `string.ToString(c1)` is what gets called. `2` resolves to `int`, so `2.ToString()` resolves to `int.ToString()` which has a type of `string`. The _implicit conversion_ rule mentioned in the spec can be understood to mean that interpolated string expressions are _target-typed_ only in the special case that the target type is `FormattableString` or `IFormattable`, otherwise it's typed as `string`.

Comment: An alternative implementation is to define `public string ToStringWith(FormattableString expression, IFormatProvider formatProvider) { return expression.ToString(formatProvider); } ... string f2 = ToStringWith($"{value:N2}", c1);`, which passes the test because the interpolated string is target-typed to `FormattableString`.

Comment: In addition to what @JeffE said you can check what is actually happening in the [decompiled](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0BxANgewEYENMBLAL3wBcjsA7AblhAGZkxEBhRAb1kV+WZAAWRAFkAFAEouPPgBNsAV1yYApogBuhBWoC8iMPAhhURxoPowAkGwWZyCgE4qAktQBm2RAGMIiPTbtHF3dsVDYnChUAZQAHFS8iNyIvAPsnMQAiWRUAWjYACQyJC0sAMWwHAFsKcnxlaPIHImoAc0Q3P0QAEgzOTUxtAC4AOTAAXwySlABOTLAAckNjI0QMgGp21AAVbCjG5paxHwli2EsUJDdWPR6+rRUR8Yzt3f3Wo4hTqxm5xaMTVgZRAbdpgYqIGS8MawMZAA==) code.

Comment: Ok, I had the (apparently wrong) expectation that the type of `$"..."` was FormattableString (with the possibility of an implicit conversion to String). That would have been conceptually cleaner IMHO. But at least I understand the behavior now.