# Is it possible to mix string resources when using string interpolation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm refactoring some code and one task is to place hard-coded strings into resources. I have this string in code:

```
var s = $"Last Updated: {DateTime.Now}";
```

So now how can I extract this string into a resource. Currently I think only this is possible:

```
var s = string.Format(MyStrings.LastUpdated, DateTime.Now);
```

where, `MyStrings.LastUpdated` would be:

```
Last Updated: {0}
```

Is this the only way or is there a newer way available?

Comment: You need to have placeholder where to output another string. Using `{0}` is as good as anything else. In your example you simply concatenate strings, but placeholder can be anywhere. [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is not an option.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070147/unexpected-behavior-of-formattablestring-tostringiformatprovider. You need to use FormattableString, but I haven't used that in resources yet.

Comment: Considering it, it is probably better to change that to the "traditional" form with "{0}". Otherwise, your translator will need to know the variable names, and he has no idea of that. And when you change your variable name (i.e. it had a typo), nobody will notice the now failing translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain interpolation expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a result string, items with interpolation expressions are replaced by the string representations of the expression results.

As stated in the language [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) for string interpolation with `$`, the operator identifies a *string literal*, so you cannot use a resource or variable for the format string itself.

Extracting the format string and formatting it using `string.Format` is a reasonable way to do this. Nevertheless, you should keep in mind that these format strings might contain complex expressions involving names or numbers and other format specifiers. So you should carefully communicate that your translator does not change or remove them, otherwise your application might show unexpected behavior. On the one hand, this might be inconvenient, but on the other hand you can only protect the expressions in your format string from modification if you separate them from your localizable resources and concatenate them yourself, which is infeasible.